# How to deactivate a existing active process builder using metadata API?

Tags: process-builder, metadata-api

**Background**:

1. There is only one version of the process builder exists in sandbox, version number is 1 and it is Active.
2. I retrieved this process builder using the command `sfdx force:source:retrieve --sourcepath=/path/to/flow --targetusername=sandbox` (API version is set to 47.0 in `sfdx-project.json`)

**Goal**:

Deactivate this process builder by deployment.

**Attempt 1**:

1. Changed value for `status` tag in flow xml to `Obsolete` and deployed using the command `sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath=/path/to/flow --targetusername=sandbox`

It didn't deactivate the existing version but created version 2 with Inactive status.

**Attempt 2**:

1. Changed value for `status` tag in flow xml to `Draft` and deployed using the command `sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath=/path/to/flow --targetusername=sandbox`

It didn't deactivate the existing version but created version 2 with Inactive status.

As per the [Flow MetadataAPI](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) documentation, `status` can be either "Obsolete" or "Draft" and both correspond to Inactive status but it seems to be not working.

I ran all of the above commands using the option `--apiversion=47.0` but still same result.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to deactivate process builder as follows:

1. Retrieved FlowDefinition file for the process builder that I am trying to deactivate using the command `sfdx force:source:retrieve --metadata=FlowDefinition:ProcessBuilderApiNameGoesHere`
2. Updated value for tag `activeVersionNumber` to 0.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <FlowDefinition xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
       <activeVersionNumber>0</activeVersionNumber>
   </FlowDefinition>
   ```
3. Did the deployment using the command `sfdx force:source:deploy --sourcepath=/path/to/flowDefinitionfile`

and it worked(process builder was deactivated).

It would be nice if we can deactivate process builder by just changing value for `status` tag in actual process builder file(flow xml) itself.

Comment: n.b. use extra spaces to get code to format inside a numbered list. It's not very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have basically answered it: You cannot deactivate it by a Metadata API deployment. Just one of those weird quirks Salesforce has put into the API for us.

You MIGHT be able to do it with Tooling API by updating either the `Flow` or `FlowDefinition` object. I haven't tested this.

Comment: One can definitely _activate_ using the Tooling API (at least on specific API versions!). I've never tried to _deactivate_.

Comment: If we can't really deactivate using metadata API, how do projects using CI/CD achieve this? Just curious..

Comment: The honest answer is, "Salesforce is not 100% properly built for CI/CD and this is just one of the things you have to hack / work around"

Comment: Or, "use scratch orgs for CI/CD".

Comment: @DavidReed OK but when the change you finally have to merge into your real production org is still something you can't do properly with Metadata API, the fact that you used scratch orgs for CI/CD won't have helped you.